# 'jpeglib.h' file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, libjpeg

I am trying to read a jpg image in c++. I downloaded [libjpg](http://www.ijg.org/) as it was suggested at this link https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Libraries and installed it. Although when I include the library Xcode fails building saying 'jpeglib.h' file not found

```
#include <jpeglib.h>
```

I can see the header in /usr/local/include/ directory so I can't understand why Xcode won't see it.

**OS and Software details:**

OSX 10.11 (El Capitan)

Xcode 7.0.1

edit:

```
find /usr/local -name \*jpeg\* -print -name \*jpg\* -print
/usr/local/bin/cjpeg
/usr/local/bin/djpeg
/usr/local/bin/jpegtran
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/cjpeg
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/djpeg
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/jpegtran
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/include/jpeglib.h
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.a
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/share/man/man1/cjpeg.1
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/share/man/man1/djpeg.1
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/share/man/man1/jpegtran.1
/usr/local/include/jpeglib.h
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib
/usr/local/Library/Aliases/libjpeg
/usr/local/Library/Aliases/libjpeg-turbo
/usr/local/Library/Formula/jpeg-archive.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/jpeg-turbo.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/jpeg.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/jpeginfo.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/jpegoptim.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/jpegrescan.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/mjpegtools.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/mozjpeg.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/openjpeg.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/recoverjpeg.rb
/usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/jpeg
/usr/local/opt/jpeg
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cjpeg.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/djpeg.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/jpegtran.1
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.deps/cdjpeg.Po
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.deps/cjpeg.Po
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.deps/djpeg.Po
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.deps/jpegtran.Po
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.libs/cjpeg
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.libs/djpeg
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.libs/jpegtran
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.libs/libjpeg.9.dylib
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.libs/libjpeg.a
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.libs/libjpeg.dylib
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.libs/libjpeg.la
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/.libs/libjpeg.lai
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/cdjpeg.c
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/cdjpeg.h
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/cdjpeg.o
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/cjpeg
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/cjpeg.1
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/cjpeg.c
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/cjpeg.o
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/djpeg
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/djpeg.1
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/djpeg.c
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/djpeg.o
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/jpegint.h
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/jpeglib.h
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/jpegtran
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/jpegtran.1
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/jpegtran.c
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/jpegtran.o
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/libjpeg.la
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/libjpeg.map
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/libjpeg.txt
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/makcjpeg.st
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/makdjpeg.st
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/makljpeg.st
/usr/local/src/jpeg-9a/maktjpeg.st
/usr/local/src/jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz
```

Comment: Please provide the output from `find /usr/local -name \*jpeg\* -print -name \*jpg\* -print`

Comment: I edited my question to show the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it looks like you just need to:

1. Add `/usr/local/include` to the *Header Search Path* (turn *recursive* **off**). [This](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/01/helping-xcode-find-library-headers/) still looks relevant.
2. Link explicitly against `/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a` from within *Link binary with libraries* ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)).  This will link in the static library, meaning there is no need to distribute the JPEG dynamic library with your app.